# Need to assign information from the result of one function to the beginning of another

Tags: python, function, file, dictionary

In this project I have to first convert a DNA strand to the complement, I've successfully created that function but I then need to assign the result of that to the next function to convert it to RNA. I'm currently sending the result to a file and attempting to import that to the next function but it isn't picking up any information, I'd appreciate any suggestions as to where I can go with this, thanks!

```
#open file with DNA strand
df = open('dnafile.txt','r')

#open file for writing all new info
wf = open('newdnafile.txt', 'r+')

#function for finding complementary strand
def encode(code,DNA):
    DNA = ''.join(code[k] for k in DNA)
    wf.write(DNA)
    print('The complementary strand is: ' + DNA)

#carrying out complement function
code = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'G':'C', 'C':'G'}
DNA = df.read()
encode(code,DNA)

#function for turning complementary strand into RNA
def final(code, complement):
    for k in code:
        complement = complement.replace(k,code[k])
    wf.write('the RNA strand is: ' + complement + '\n')
    print('the RNA strand is: ' + complement)

#carrying out RNA function
code = {'T':'U'}
#following line is where the issue arises:
complement = wf.read()
final(code,complement)
```

Every time I carry this out it prints "The RNA strand is: " and fails to return any strand.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are sending the information to a file?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have to send info to that file later in the program so I thought it may be an easy way to call that variable but I haven't had much luck yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that once you write to the file the cursor is set to the end of the file, thus it is reading nothing. Before `complement = wf.read()` use `wf.seek(0)` and it should work.

In general, you should use global file objects like this - it's asking for trouble. Also, avoid using `r+` unless you have to, it can be a bit tricky. You should really be wrapping your usage of files in a `with` block:

For example, at the top use:

```
with open('dnafile.txt', 'r+') as df:
    DNA = df.read()
```

This makes sure that the file is *closed* at the end of the block. Note, you never closed your files, which is a bad habit (it won't affect anything here, really).

Finally, it doesn't make sense to use a file to communicate between functions in the same script. Just `return` the appropriate value from one function and feed it into the other.